# Laplace Transform with unit step function

Tags: laplace-transform

Here is the link to the question and the answer: 
https://gyazo.com/d98918d0e0eaabe88606c0314aff0aca

Here is the link to what I have done: 
https://gyazo.com/20ddc3822c0c7bca888cd3334dd78281

What happens to 3PI? Where does it go?

Comment: Can you change it Mathjax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify that:$$\sin(\pi t+3\pi)=-\sin(\pi t)$$
since
$$\sin(a\pm b)=\sin a\cos b\mp \sin b\cos a$$
Alternatively, notice that the period of $\sin(\pi t)$ is $\dfrac{2\pi}{\pi}=2$, which means values of sine repeat for $t+2k$ where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, while the sign alternates for $t+k$.

Comment: When can you rewrite it like this? Is there a formula for this?

Comment: @David Lund I've added some more info to my answer

Comment: Can I just draw a unit circle and go 3pi rounds starting at sin until I end up at -sin. would that be the same?

Comment: In this case, yes, that's the basic geometric explanation of what's going on here.